# Cat is shaking and sleeping

Tags: cats, health

I got a 4 year old Sphynx cat 6 days ago. He’s been sleeping a lot and shaking constantly when he’s awake. I took him to the vet and he said he thinks this is nothing to worry about. I’m concerned as he is drinking quite a bit too. Any ideas of what this could be?

Comment: do you have other pets? does the cat eat the food you give and did the vet take a bloodsample from your cat.if the shaking keeps going you need to take him to the vet(cats do normally not shake/shiver unless something is wrong and you need a vet to find the cause),does the cat pee more than 3-4 times a day?

Comment: I agree with Trond Hansen. If a cat is shaking in a warm environment, it's always a bad sign. If this vet didn't find anything, try another one.

Comment: Yes he is eating the food that I give him. He will get up to eat some food then go and lay back down after he has finished. The cat is not peeing more than 3 times a day. The vet only checked him over, they didn’t take any bloods from him.

Comment: At the risk of sounding stupid are you sure the cat isn't shaking because it's cold? I only raise this as you mentioned that it's a sphynx cat which are hairless.

Comment: I have a little cat jumper on him, heating on and when he’s under the covers he still shakes so I don’t think it’s because he is cold. He is also eating wet food. I took him to the vets again today they are going to take a blood sample from him on Monday.

Answer (score 7):

It is normal for cats to sleep up to 20 hours a day see [How many hours a day is it normal for a cat to sleep?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/3074/13)

Cats normally don't drink much water see [How do I motivate a cat to drink more water?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1881/13)

Prolonged shaking is not normal in any mammal.

You don't mention the vet doing any lab work, so I have to assume he did not do any.  Take your cat to a different vet and request lab work.

Other considerations; you don't say where you got the cat, but if the cat was poorly cared for in its previous home.  high fluid intake and nervous shaking could be related to previous experience and poor care.

Comment: Note that the amount a cat drinks (and what is normal) depends on whether you feed them dry or wet food. Cats can mostly get by on the moisture from wet food but dry food requires them to hydrate separately.